How to change structure of articles in django-wiki?
I am new to django-wiki and want to change the structure of article form.
As default has Title, contents and summary. I want to add 2 more fields for "main" and "history".
How can do that? Thanks in advance.
I tried looking it up on the internet but sources are scarce.

Add code example please.
